# Rxjs: Make sure returned Observable is getting executed

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I hope this question won't get *opinion marked* because I'm actually looking for technical flaws in my concept.

Most of my functions returning observables should make sure they're getting executed anyway and just inform the caller if he is interessted.

E.g. if I have a login-method `login(username, password): Observable<User>` I want to make sure the method gets executed wether the caller is interessted or not. Right now I always use the same pattern in this case:

```
login(username, password): Observable<User> {
   let result = queryUser(username, password).pipe(
      //pretty many things may happen here
   );

   //Make the observable hot
   result = result.pipe(share());
   result.subscribe();

   return result;
}
```

Is this a bad practice for some reason or a pretty common implementation? Should share() be called first or last?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a common use-case. The point of returning an Observable is that you can unsubscribe it if you want to cancel the action which is not possible the way you're using it.

Comment: In this case I'm using an Observable to be able to inform the caller about the logged in user. But if the caller just isn't interessted he'd call `login('username', 'password')` and the login will never happen. Just like a Promise would be executed without a `.than()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @martin, I would advise **not** to use this kind of behaviour because it would break the reactive context.

Subscribing/Unsubscring to the function wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: But thats actually what I want! Otherwise I could use a promise for this (or wrap all usaged like `from(service.login())`), but Observables are just more powerful.